# Folder authorization in asp.net Identity 2.1

Tags: .net, authorization, asp.net-identity

I searched but couldn't find role based authorization for access to folders or files in .net identity 2.1 as there is in form based authorization

```
    <location path="Pictures">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow roles="Administrators"/> //Allows users in Admin role
         <deny users="*"/> // deny everyone else
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Is there any way to implement this in .net identity?

Comment: Did my answer help? Just curious, since there is no feedback at all. If not, perhaps I could improve the answer.

Comment: Your answer was helpful indeed in the sense that now I know there is no simple way to implement role based authorization for access to folders or files in .net identity 2.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a filter:

```
public class FilterStaticFilesAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var request = actionContext.Request;

        if (request.RequestUri.LocalPath.StartsWith("\Pictures", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (!request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
            {
                actionContext.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                return;
            }
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Register in WebApiConfig.Register:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Filters.Add(new FilterStaticFilesAttribute());
}
```

What this does: alle requests will pass the registered filter. Inside the filter determine if it is a call to the static files location. Only if the user has the role of Administrators then access is granted.

Comment: I tried this method but it turns out that the HttpActionContext.Request object does not have the GetOwinContext() method. Any ways around this?